# array of two dimensions

Tags: java

I want to calculate the difference between the elements of 2 matrix:
example:

```
s1 = tuple[0][0]-vector[0][0]+tuple[0][1]-vector[0][1]
s2 = tuple[0][0]-vector[1][0]+tuple[0][1]-vector[1][1]
s3 = tuple[0][0]-vector[2][0]+tuple[0][1]-vector[2][1]

static double Distance1(double[][] tuple, double[][] vector)
{
    double sumSquaredDiffs =0.0;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0; i<tuple.length;i++)
        for(j=0; j<vector.length; j++){
            sumSquaredDiffs = tuple[i][0] - vector[j][0]+ tuple[i][1] - vector[j][1];
        }
        return sumSquaredDiffs;
    }
}
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
13.0
125.0
123.0
10.0
122.0
120.0
```

Can someone please help me correct this function?

Comment: do you mean you want to subtract one matrix from another?

Comment: yes like in the example above

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

```
//Assuming that no. of rows and columns in both matrices are same 
static double Distance1(double[][] arr1, double[][] arr2)
{
  double[][] result = new double[arr1.length][arr2[0].length];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < arr1[i].length ; j++)
    {
        result[i][j] = arr1[i][j] - arr2[i][j];
    }
  }
 //Printing Result
 for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < result.length ; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(result[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: this is my prob, the rows and columns are not same of both matrices

Comment: If two matrices don't have same number of rows and columns then they can't be subtracted..This is the fundamental rule of matrix subtraction..!!!

Comment: well i want to subtracte every line from the first matrice from all line in the second matrice.

Comment: You keep changing your question.. Now you are saying that you want every line from first matrix to subtract from all line of other matrix, does it means that both matrix have same number of rows and columns.

Comment: sorry ...this is my question from the beginning, but just the number of columns must be the same.